# Open source antivirus/antispam/web filtering gateway

Tags: firewall, anti-virus, open-source, spam, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Source Unified Threat Management Software Options](https://serverfault.com/questions/27570/open-source-unified-threat-management-software-options)

I want to install firewall which have following features Antispam, Anti Virus, Webfiltering, Userwise access, Intrusion prevention etc. is any product from open source )(ie untangle/ipcop) any other solution for the above implementation if any one can help me with this.

Comment: This is similar to this other question: http://serverfault.com/questions/27570/open-source-unified-threat-management-software-options/27584#27584

Comment: Don't forget the paradox of defense in depth -- which is that the more security products you layer into your perimeter, the more you increase your chances that one of those products will itself have a security vulnerability that will open your network to compromise. Have you thought through exactly what security features you need and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pfsense](http://www.pfsense.com/) can do most of this if you add extra packages which are easily installable inside the distribution. It is also very stable and intuitive to use.

Answer (score 0):

Look at **[Endian Firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endian_Firewall)**

Endian **[Download](http://www.endian.com/en/community/download/)**

> The Endian Firewall is an open source Linux distribution that specializes on Routing/Firewalling and Unified Threat Management